# Error: does not override abstract method onClick(View) in OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

```
private OnClickListener onButtonClick = new OnClickListener() {
      //  @Override
        public void OnClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.play: {
                    if (player.isPlaying()) {
                        handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
                        player.pause();
                        playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                    } else {
                        if (isStarted) {
                            player.start();
                            playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);

                            updatePosition();
                        } else {
                            startPlay(currentFile);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.next: {
                    int seekto = player.getCurrentPosition() + STEP_VALUE;

                    if (seekto > player.getDuration())
                        seekto = player.getDuration();
                    player.pause();
                    ;
                    player.seekTo(seekto);
                    player.start();

                    break;
                }
                case R.id.prev: {
                    int seekto = player.getCurrentPosition() - STEP_VALUE;
                    if (seekto < 0)
                        seekto = 0;

                    player.pause();
                    player.seekTo(seekto);
                    player.start();

                    break;
                }

            }

        }

    };

    private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletion = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            stopPlay();
        }
    };

    private MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener onError = new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
       // @Override
        public boolean OnError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChanged = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        //@Override
        public void OnStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            isMoveingSeekBar = false;
        }

        //@Override
        public void OnStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            isMoveingSeekBar = true;
        }

        //@Override
        public void OnProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (isMoveingSeekBar)
            {
                player.seekTo(progress);
            Log.i("OnSeekBarChangedListener", "OnProgressChanged");
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I'm getting this after gradle build:

> Error:(189, 67) error:  is not abstract and
>   does not override abstract method onClick(View) in OnClickListener
>
> Error:(248, 85) error:  is not abstract and
>   does not override abstract method onError(MediaPlayer,int,int) in
>   OnErrorListener
>
> Error:(255, 100) error:  is not abstract and
>   does not override abstract method onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar) in
>   OnSeekBarChangeListener
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Uncomment `@Override`

Comment: Lowercase `on` in method names, not `On`

Comment: What @laalto said too. You can't change method names that you're overriding, and the error is telling you that you either need to override them or declare your class abstract.

Comment: If you had the `@Override` annotation uncommented, the compiler would tell you that your method isn't an override. It isn't an override because the method name is different.

Comment: Your IDE should help you with errors like that... or do you use a simple text editor?

Comment: @Shark Thanks.It worked.

Comment: @khelwood Yes, firstly I was running the app by uncommenting **@Override** only. But wasn't able to pick up that I have used **O** instead of **o** accidentally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the methods that have the `// @Override` line before them are not the correct method names for each `interface`. As @laalto pointed out, each of these method names should start with "`on`" instead of "`On`". Then the `@Override` annotation will not produce an error (as it is overriding the correct method), and you can uncomment them. This *should* be the correct code:

```
private OnClickListener onButtonClick = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.play:
                if (player.isPlaying()) {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
                    player.pause();
                    playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                else {
                    if (isStarted) {
                        player.start();
                        playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
                        updatePosition();
                    } else {
                        startPlay(currentFile);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case R.id.next:
                int seekto = player.getCurrentPosition() + STEP_VALUE;

                if (seekto > player.getDuration()) {
                        seekto = player.getDuration();
                }

                player.pause();
                player.seekTo(seekto);
                player.start();

                break;
            case R.id.prev:
                int seekto = player.getCurrentPosition() - STEP_VALUE;
                if (seekto < 0) {
                    seekto = 0;
                }

                player.pause();
                player.seekTo(seekto);
                player.start();

                break;
        }
    }
};

private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletion = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        stopPlay();
    }
};

private MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener onError = new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        return false;
    }
};

private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChanged = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        isMoveingSeekBar = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void OnStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        isMoveingSeekBar = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void OnProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (isMoveingSeekBar) {
            player.seekTo(progress);
            Log.i("OnSeekBarChangedListener", "OnProgressChanged");
        }
    }
};
```

Android Studio also has bunch of [autocomplete features](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/auto-completing-code.html) that will take care of implementing `interface` methods for you, you should use them to your advantage. In this way you should be able to start typing the name of the `interface`, and then you should see a prompt like this:

[image]

Then you can just press `return` (`enter` on Windows) to autocomplete the implementation:

[image]